# EmberJs model output into an img tag in a handlebar template

Tags: image, ember.js, laravel-4, handlebars.js

I am trying to learn EmberJs, in conjuction with Laravel 4, to create a blog. Things have been going great, stuff hasn't been too difficult yet. But I got into a snag when trying to have a `<img/>` tag in one of my handlebar templates.

From my understanding to use info from a model in a template you use `{{attribute_name}}` and like magic, it's there! And so for my tag I was trying something like:

```
<img src="{{URL::asset('images/posts/')}}@{{id}}.@{{image_extension}}" }}" alt=""/>
```

Adding the url to images with Laravel and Blade, then on the template, just adding in those last little pieces to make the it all work. But I get this instead:

```
<img src="http://localhost/blog/images/posts&lt;script id='metamorph-11-start' type='text/x-placeholder'&gt;&lt;/script&gt;26&lt;script id='metamorph-11-end' type='text/x-placeholder'&gt;&lt;/script&gt;.&lt;script id='metamorph-12-start' type='text/x-placeholder'&gt;&lt;/script&gt;jpg&lt;script id='metamorph-12-end' type='text/x-placeholder'&gt;&lt;/script&gt;" alt="">
```

Obviously theres script tags in my src tag and this is causing some issues.

Now then, upon much research I discovered `{{unbound attribute_name}}` and came up with:

```
<img src="{{URL::asset('images/posts')}}/@{{unbound id}}.@{{unbound image_extension}}" alt=""/>
```

and while this works on the first blog post I click, it doesn't switch images when I switch posts. So is there a way to make this guy work? I'm running out of ideas! Any information you could shed on this would be great! I really like ember so far and want to get even better! IF there's any more info you need, let em know and I will edit this question! Thanks so much!

EDIT:
Based on the advise from @buruzaemon, I tried

```
<img src="{{URL::asset('images/posts')}}/@{{bind-attr src=id}}.@{{bind-attr src=image_extension}}" alt="Post image"/>
```

and it feels like it's on the right path, but not quite there. Any more advice?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should have a look at [`bind_attr`](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/binding-element-attributes/) in Ember.js. It will allow you to set the `src` attribute properly with value that can be set in your controller.

Comment: I see that I can add that in, but won't that erase the value from Laravel's {{URL::asset('images/posts/')}}? with localhost/foo/images/image.png?

Comment: Actually, I think you would try something like `<img {{bind_attr src=imgUrl}} >`. Is it possible to compute the string value for the `src` attribute in your controller?

Comment: The thing is, I have the filename and extension separate. The file name is the id of the post, and the extensions is separate so I have two different attributes that need to work together.

Comment: Controllers in Ember deal with properties or logic that are displayed, but do not need to be saved to the server with the model. If the `id` and `image_extension` values are within the context of your template, then you should be able to construct the string for the `src` attribute with the related Ember controller as a property, and then invoke that with `{{bind_attr src=...}}`.

Comment: id and image extension, both are loaded via ajax to a model.